# Number of binary tree with n node and n-3 height

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

How many binary trees can find that have n Node and the height of these tress are n-3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of Binary Tree possible with `n` nodes = **(<sup>2n</sup>C<sub>n</sub>) / (n+1)**.

The minimum depth of a binary tree is **⌊log<sub>2</sub>n⌋** and the maximum depth is `n-1`.

So in each level there will be **[(<sup>2n</sup>C<sub>n</sub>) / (n+1)] / [(n-1) - (⌊log<sub>2</sub>n⌋)]** nodes.